# Unhandled Rejection (Error): No response from server (anonymous function)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, .net

I was able to run a conference app.
Now I am on Trailhead module "Access Salesforce Data with Lightning Web Components Open Source"
In step "Connect to Salesforce" I am trying to run npm. Getting this error

[image: VS Code Terminal Message]

[image: Web Browser]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your file supposed to be saved as '.env', as per the trailhead module file name should be just '.env'. I tried giving other names to the file but the build fails.
[image]

More on '.env' file
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to explain more and/or include more details. From what I can see, there is indeed an `.env` file (`process.env`)